# How to Disabled 1 button yet keep others enabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When the `$order_status` is *Accepted* only the button containing *Accept* is disabled. And If `$order_status` is *Dispatched* the disabled button is sent. And if `$order_status` is *Cancelled* the disabled button is Cancel. I'm new in php im not quiete understand  it.

The button containing text *Accept* is disabled - even if the value of `$order_status` is *accepted*, *dispatched* or *cancelled*. Why is it always disabled?

below is the code:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" 
    <?php if ($order_status = 'Accepted'){?> disabled <?php } ?>">Accept </button> 

<button type="submit" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary" >Sent</button> 

<button type="submit" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" 
    onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some code to have a change at helping. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <button type="submit" name="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" <?php if ($order_status = 'Accepted'){?> disabled <?php } ?>">Accept </button>
 <button type="submit" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary" >Sent</button> 
 <button type="submit" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel</button> sorry, i forgot. thats the code

Comment: @Blank, you need to add that code to the question. Would be much easier and cleaner...

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit to separate your concerns. First start with your HTML and as little PHP as possible:

```
<button
  type="submit"
  name="submitAccept"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  <?php if ($submitAcceptDisabled): ?> disabled <?php endif ?>">
  Accept
</button>
```

The same goes for your other buttons, simply add a flag and keep your view simple. For your PHP logic let's investigate your scenarios:

1. When the order_status is Accepted only accept button is disabled.

   ```
   $submitAcceptDisabled = $order_status === 'Accepted';
   ```
2. And If order_status is Dispatched the disabled button is sent.

   ```
   $submitSentDisabled = $order_status === 'Dispatched';
   ```
3. And if order_status is Cancelled the disabled button is Cancel.

   ```
   $submitCancelDisabled = $order_status === 'Cancelled';
   ```

In your piece of code you assign a value to `$order_status` rather than checking if the current value equals something:

```
if ($order_status = 'Accepted')
```

This will always set the value of `Accepted` to the `$order_status` variable.

Another improvement you could consider is to separate your Javascript:

```
const submitCancel = document.querySelector('button[name="submitCancel"]');
submitCancel.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: <?php
 $submitAcceptDisabled = $order_status === 'Accepted';
?>
 <button type="submit" name="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" <?php if ($submitAcceptDisabled): ?> disabled <?php endif ?>" > Accept </button>
 <button type="submit" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary" >Sent</button> 
 <button type="submit" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel</button> | Thats my code for now. sad to say. it enable the accept button. But when i delete the endif it back to disabled all accept button. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not the same as in my example; you use:
`$submitAcceptDisabled = $order_status === 'Accepted'; `

If you don't save seperate _flags_ (like $submitAcceptDisabled) which will make your view more clear, you should only use: `$order_status === 'Accepted'`

Answer (score 0):

The lone equal sign in your conditional statement is not a "[Comparison Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)", it is an "[Assignment Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)".

If you write:

```
$order_status='Dispatched';
if($order_status='Accepted'){  // this sets the value
    echo "order_status=$order_status";  // this displays the new value
}else{
    echo "order_status=$order_status";  // this doesn't get a chance to happen
}
```

You will see:

```
order_status=Accepted
```

This is because the if statement is behaving like a declaration instead a comparison.  To make your if statement compare the variable to the value, you can use `==` (loose comparison, aka true after "type juggling") or `===` (strict comparison, aka "identical").

For your task, you can use this snippet that employs inline-conditions in a single php code block.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55725056526389a0cf94576e8459a4f8fbd960b5))

```
echo "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submitAccept\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"",($order_status=='Accepted'?' disabled':''),">Accept<button>";
echo "\n";
echo "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submitSend\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"",($order_status=='Dispatched'?' disabled':''),">Send<button>";
echo "\n";
echo "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submitCancel\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"",($order_status=='Cancelled'?' disabled':'')," onclick=\"if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}\">Cancel<button>";
```

Unrendered HTML Output:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Accept<button>
<button type="submit" name="submitSend" class="btn btn-primary">Send<button>
<button type="submit" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel<button>
```

A couple of extra notes:

- You had an extra `"` after `?>` in your code here: `?>">Accept </button>`
- I change `Sent` to `Send` in my snippet for improved English